# Change directory for azure subscription back to default

Tags: entra-id, subscription

My Azure subscription is associated with an MS Live account, which was later also included in the AD Directory of my old company, but although apparently disabled there when I left was still available in the list of Directories in Azure Portal. I have inadvertently switched to it and since then remain locked out of Azure Portal. 
The steps are:

1. go to portal.azure.com
2. enter account name / email
3. enter password
4. click Yes to Stay Signed in
5. now I start getting [the following screen with an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRD5c.png), the URL being microsoftonline.com and one of the parameters actually what I think is the name of the tenant of the old company
6. This message blinks for about half a dozen times, interleaved with a white screen to login.live.com
7. finally the ["too many attempts message"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2JVi.png)  appears and stuck there.

So I work my way though 5(!) Azure support teams passing it to each other by now,  but no resolution yet. Is there any process that I could do on my side to switch back to whatever the default Directory for a Live/personal account in Azure Portal should be and log back in?
I can log into the Account portal just fine.

Comment: It’s not clear. Is the personal account you setup using the same company provided email you used to have? Or are the two login IDs different? Have you tried running your browser in incognito mode or deleting all your cache and cookies? At most, your personal email should be linked as a contact in the old company, but should not affect you logging in at all unless you’re actually trying to login with an old company email address.

Comment: Thanks for replying! It is just one account, the account is my personal email address at a public server, such as Google Mail or so. It does not correspond to that company domain but is a MS Live/personal account. They just had to add it to their AD somehow, then locked it when I left? I can now see their Directory / Tenant name being passed to login.microsoftonline.com during the sign-in sequence, but that ends in the Account Locked error. Note that I can log into the Azure Accounts [portal] just fine, the password verification appears to pass every time. Yes I tried clearing cookies etc.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I’m a little confused on what symptoms you are experiencing. You shouldn’t be redirected to your company’s directory unless you enter an email address that is part of their domain. Perhaps I’m overlooking the obvious, but it may be more beneficial for you if you could [edit] your post outlining the actual process and steps you are following and the results you are seeing. Screenshots would help a lot, with the obvious redaction of private info. Please take us step by step through the logon process.

Comment: I've updated the description with steps and screenshots. I keep getting suggestions from Microsoft Azure Technical support to reset my password but I believe that the fact that I can log into the account.azure.com portal no problem, and also that I passed the password screen and got the the "Stay signed in" dialog is kind of contrary to this explanation. Also eventually I should not see that other company tenant (name or id) anywhere in the process, but it always comes up in the URL in screen [1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to log in your purpose tenant in the azure portal, you could use this url to log in: https://portal.azure.com/your-tenant-name. By this way, it will redirect you to your tenant and not to your now default tenant.

Comment: Sounds great. But what is the tenant [name] for a MS Live account, which by definition is not a part of any corporate tenant, but would belong to some default generic tenant I suppose?

Comment: The tenant name is your AD Directory that you want to back.

Comment: Internally Microsoft calls the tenant for these MS Live accounts "Outlook tenant" because they are there with the "Outlook" accounts but that's all that I can find out, not it's name or ID. So the resolution was finally, in order for me to be able to use the url above, to create a fresh new "company" tenant, add my azure account to it and then switch to it when logging in from the default directory causing the problem by navigating to the above link after you've been signed in but before you are redirected to the portal itself, in a new tab while waiting for the Stay signed In dialog. Phew!